# How do I add markup within an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site that uses a set of templates I have no control over. I can't go in and edit the HTML, but I can add CSS. I'm trying to get more control over how a profile listing looks by wrapping a span around some text. I've seen similar things done using jQuery, but I haven't been able to get anything to work in this case.

This is the current markup:

```
<h4>
  <a href="...">
    Person's Name
    <img width="120" height="122" alt="" src="...">
  </a>
</h4>
```

The problem I have is that there's no way to control the margins around the `Person's Name` text inside this a tag using css without also applying to the image.

What I want to do is add a `<span>` after the first part of the a tag, then close with `</span>` before the `img` tag to wrap the name in a span I can target with CSS. I'm guessing adding the `</span>` wouldn't be too hard using `.before`, but adding the opening `<span>` has me stumped.

What's the best way to do this if I'm using jQuery?

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have been more clear, this is wrapped in a div with a class so it currently looks like this:

```
<div class="profile">
  <h4>
    <a href="...">
      Person's Name
      <img width="120" height="122" alt="" src="...">
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

The aim would be something like this:

```
<div class="profile">
  <h4>
    <a href="...">
      <span>Person's Name</span>
      <img width="120" height="122" alt="" src="...">
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add a left margin to the `img` tag?

Comment: Is that the actual code? There are no classes or IDs? If that's the case, it will be difficult to use jQuery on just this, since you won't be able to select just that specific tag.

Comment: Unless you want to apply this to all anchor tags, or all image tags, etc. that is.

Comment: Have you got any JQuery that you have attempted so far? Specifically the parts that identify the correct `a` elements. Also, it's probably helpful in these types of questions to include an example of what you want the result HTML to look like, just to be 100% clear

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate, I spent about an hour reading through other questions too. If that one had popped up it would have saved a lot of time!

Comment: For those interested, this did the job. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

    <script>
      $('.profile > h4 > a').each(
        function(){
          $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
      });
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

Get the contents, filter it to be non-empty text nodes, and wrap with an element, such as a `span`:

```js
 $('h4 > a')
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '';
    })
    .wrap('<span/>');
```

```css
h4 > a > span{
  background-color:red  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>
  <a href="...">
    Person's Name
    <img width="120" height="122" alt="" src="...">
  </a>
</h4>
```